# Find all text within square brackets using regex

Tags: regex

I have a problem that because of PHP version, I need to change my code from `$array[stringindex]` to `$array['stringindex'];`

So I want to find all the text using regex, and replace them all. How to find all strings that look like this? `$array[stringindex]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of the tool you want to use to do the replacement.
with sed for exemple, it would be something like that:

```
sed "s/\(\$array\)\[\([^]]*\)\]/\1['\2']/g"
```

Comment: I'm currently using Sublime Text right now, will it be the same?

Comment: It seems to be like Java regex format : regex= (\$array)\[([^]]*)\], replacement = $1['$2']

Comment: Sublime Text uses boost library (Pearl syntax). See [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution in PHP:

```
$re = "/(\\$[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]+\\[)([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]+)(\\])/"; 
$str = "here is \$array[stringindex] but not \$array['stringindex'] nor \$3array[stringindex] nor \$array[4stringindex]"; 
$subst = "$1'$2'$3"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

You can [try it out interactively here](https://regex101.com/r/xI5yA8/1). I search for variables beginning with a letter, otherwise things like `$foo[42]` would be converted to `$foo['42']`, which might not be desirable.

Note that all the solutions here will not handle every case correctly.

Looking at the [Sublime Text regex help](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html), it would seem you could just paste `(\\$[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]+\\[)([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]+)(\\])` into the Search box and `$1'$2'$3` into the Replace field.

Answer (score 1):

If [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is allowed you could simply do:

```
sed -i "s/(\$[^[]*[)([^]]*)]/\1'\2']/g" file
```

Explanation:

- `sed "s/pattern/replace/g"` is a `sed` command which searches for pattern and replaces it with replace. The `g` options means replace multiple times per line.
- `(\$[^[]*[)([^]]*)]` this pattern consists of two groups (in between brackets). The first is a dollar followed by a series of non `[` chars. Then an opening square bracket follows, followed by a series of non closing brackets which is then followed by a closing square bracket.
- `\1'\2']` the replacement string: `\1` means insert the first captured group (analogous for `\2`. Basically we wrap `\2` in quotes (which is what you wanted).
- the `-i` options means that the changes should be applied to the original file, which is supplied at the end.

For more information, see `man sed`.

This can be combined with the [find](/questions/tagged/find) command, as follows:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sed -i "s/(\$[^[]*[)([^]]*)]/\1'\2']/g" '{}' \;
```

This will apply the sed command to all `php` files found.